# installing libjpeg for pil and Google app engine on mac Mountain Lion

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library, libjpeg, installation

I'm sure there's a duplicate of this somewhere out there but I looked and am about at the end of my rope.  I'm trying get PIL working on my mac OS X 10.8 so that I can use `dev_appserver.py` to test an imaging feature.  First I had trouble installing PIL until I got Homebrew and installed it using `brew install pil`.  I was under the opinion that brew installed all the necessary dependencies but when I tried to resize a jpeg in my app, it says `IOError: decoder jpeg is not available`.  So I looked online and most places said I needed to (1) uninstall PIL, (2) install libjpeg from source and (3) reinstall PIL.  So, I `brew uninstall PIL`, and then

```
curl -O www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz
tar zxvf jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz
cd jpeg-7d/
./configure
make
make install
```

and finally `brew install pil`.  I restart dev_appserver.py and reload the page on localhost, but same error.  I tested pil out from the `python` command-line with

```
>>> from PIL.Image import Image
>>> f = open("someimagefile", "rb")
>>> i = Image()
>>> i.fromstring(f.read(), decoder_name="jpeg")
Traceback blah blah blah
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

I don't have much experience installing utilities from command-line, so I probably missed something obvious.  Again, sorry if there are duplicates, but like I said, I looked and couldn't find anything that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL did not found libjpeg headers during compilation. Consult your build system documentation on how to specify headers ("includes") location, eg. as environment variables.

Comment: Now I seem to be having trouble finding libjpeg.  I attempted to install it multiple times using brew and installing it from source.  I found a folder called `jpeg` in `/usr/local/Cellar` where I think brew put it.  I tried setting `JPEG_ROOT` in setup.py to `/usr/local/Cellar` and running `python setup.py build`.  But when I did the selftest it showed it still didn't have a jpeg decoder.  I tried it again for /usr/local/lib/ because I saw libjpeg.dylib there but still didn't work.  Again, I'm a novice when it comes to installing utilities with UNIX so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working!  Thanks to @zgoda and this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/asidoothings/python-pil).  Here are the steps I ended up with for those of you who have the same problem:

First make sure PIL is not installed.  Download libjpeg from http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz, unpacked it, `./configure`, and `make`.  When I tried to `make install` it couldn't find the directory to store the man pages so installation failed.  I looked at the information on the above link and decided to

`cp -r ~/Downloads/jpeg-6d/ /usr/local/jpeg`

I suspect if the installation goes fine than that line isn't necessary.

Then edit the following line in PIL's setup.py:

```
JPEG_ROOT = None
```

to

```
JPEG_ROOT = "/usr/local/jpeg"
```

finally:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful. Can I just clarify for other readers (since I missed it): after the copy step, you need to `sudo make install`. That is also described [here](http://gpiot.com/mac-os-x-lion-install-the-python-image-library-pil/). I did not need to also edit `setup.py` or execute it.